# Set values in numpy array to NaN by index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I want to set specific values in a numpy array to `NaN` (to exclude them from a row-wise mean calculation).

I tried

```
import numpy

x = numpy.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
cutoff = [5, 7]
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i][0:cutoff[i]:1] = numpy.nan
```

Looking at `x`, I only see `-9223372036854775808` where I expect `NaN`.

I thought about an alternative:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for k in range(cutoff[i]):
        x[i][k] = numpy.nan
```

Nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you have nan's in an integer array? Does `dtype=float` `x[0][0:5] = np.nan;x[1][0:7] = np.nan` work?

Comment: If you use @Divakar's solution you can just avoid the nan issue `mask = np.asarray(cutoff)[:,None] > np.arange(x.shape[1])` `answer = np.ma.masked_where(mask, x).mean(axis=1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Vectorized approach to set appropriate elements as NaNs**

[@unutbu's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019701/3293881) must get rid of the value error you were getting. If you are looking to `vectorize` for performance, you can use [`boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) like so -

```
import numpy as np

# Create mask of positions in x (with float datatype) where NaNs are to be put
mask = np.asarray(cutoff)[:,None] > np.arange(x.shape[1])

# Put NaNs into masked region of x for the desired ouput
x[mask] = np.nan
```

Sample run -

```
In [92]: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,7)).astype(float)

In [93]: x
Out[93]: 
array([[ 2.,  1.,  5.,  2.,  5.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  5.,  7.,  1.,  5.,  4.,  8.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  7.,  4.,  8.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 5.,  8.,  7.,  5.,  0.,  2.,  1.]])

In [94]: cutoff = [5,3,0,6]

In [95]: x[np.asarray(cutoff)[:,None] > np.arange(x.shape[1])] = np.nan

In [96]: x
Out[96]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   2.,   1.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,   5.,   4.,   8.],
       [  1.,   1.,   7.,   4.,   8.,   3.,   1.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   1.]])
```

---

**Vectorized approach to directly calculate row-wise mean of appropriate elements**

If you were trying to get the masked mean values, you can modify the earlier proposed vectorized approach to avoid dealing with `NaNs` altogether and more importantly keep `x` with integer values. Here's the modified approach -

```
# Get array version of cutoff
cutoff_arr = np.asarray(cutoff)

# Mask of positions in x which are to be considered for row-wise mean calculations
mask1 = cutoff_arr[:,None] <= np.arange(x.shape[1])

# Mask x, calculate the corresponding sum and thus mean values for each row
masked_mean_vals = (mask1*x).sum(1)/(x.shape[1] -  cutoff_arr)
```

Here's a sample run for such a solution -

```
In [61]: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,7))

In [62]: x
Out[62]: 
array([[5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 2, 0],
       [3, 2, 0, 7, 5, 0, 2],
       [7, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3],
       [4, 1, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8]])

In [63]: cutoff = [5,3,0,6]

In [64]: cutoff_arr = np.asarray(cutoff)

In [65]: mask1 = cutoff_arr[:,None] <= np.arange(x.shape[1])

In [66]: mask1
Out[66]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [67]: masked_mean_vals = (mask1*x).sum(1)/(x.shape[1] -  cutoff_arr)

In [68]: masked_mean_vals
Out[68]: array([ 1.        ,  3.5       ,  3.14285714,  8.        ])
```

Answer (score 11):

`nan` is a floating-point value. When `x` is an array with integer dtype, it can not be assigned a nan value. When `nan` is assigned to an array of integer dtype, the value is automatically converted to an int:

```
In [85]: np.array(np.nan).astype(int).item()
Out[85]: -9223372036854775808
```

So to fix your code, make `x` an array of float dtype:

```
x = numpy.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], 
                dtype=float)
```

---

```
import numpy

x = numpy.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], 
                dtype=float)
cutoff = [5, 7]
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i][0:cutoff[i]:1] = numpy.nan
 print(x)
```

yields

```
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   0.,   1.,   0.]])
```