# Python get get average of neighbours in matrix with na value

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have very large matrix, so dont want to sum by going through each row and column.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]]
def neighbors(i,j,a):
    return [a[i][j-1], a[i][(j+1)%len(a[0])], a[i-1][j], a[(i+1)%len(a)][j]]
[[np.mean(neighbors(i,j,a)) for j in range(len(a[0]))] for i in range(len(a))]
```

This code works well for 3x3 or small range of matrix, but for large matrix like  2k x 2k this is not feasible. Also this does not work if any of the value in matrix is missing or it's like `na`

This code works well for 3x3 or small range of matrix, but for large matrix like  2k x 2k this is not feasible. Also this does not work if any of the value in matrix is missing or it's like `na`. If any of the neighbor values is `na` then skip that neighbour in getting the average

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Shot #1

This assumes you are looking to get sliding windowed average values in an input array with a window of `3 x 3` and considering only the north-west-east-south neighborhood elements.

For such a case, [`signal.convolve2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) with an appropriate kernel could be used. At the end, you need to divide those summations by the number of ones in kernel, i.e. `kernel.sum()` as only those contributed to the summations. Here's the implementation -

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

# Inputs
a = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7],[4,8,9]]

# Convert to numpy array
arr = np.asarray(a,float)    

# Define kernel for convolution                                         
kernel = np.array([[0,1,0],
                   [1,0,1],
                   [0,1,0]]) 

# Perform 2D convolution with input data and kernel 
out = signal.convolve2d(arr, kernel, boundary='wrap', mode='same')/kernel.sum()
```

### Shot #2

This makes the same assumptions as in shot #1, except that we are looking to find average values in a neighborhood of only zero elements with the intention to replace them with those average values.

**Approach #1:** Here's one way to do it using a manual selective convolution approach -

```
import numpy as np

# Convert to numpy array
arr = np.asarray(a,float)    

# Pad around the input array to take care of boundary conditions
arr_pad = np.lib.pad(arr, (1,1), 'wrap')

R,C = np.where(arr==0)   # Row, column indices for zero elements in input array
N = arr_pad.shape[1]     # Number of rows in input array

offset = np.array([-N, -1, 1, N])
idx = np.ravel_multi_index((R+1,C+1),arr_pad.shape)[:,None] + offset

arr_out = arr.copy()
arr_out[R,C] = arr_pad.ravel()[idx].sum(1)/4
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [587]: arr
Out[587]: 
array([[ 4.,  0.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  1.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  4.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  1.]])

In [588]: arr_out
Out[588]: 
array([[ 4.  ,  3.5 ,  3.  ,  3.  ,  3.  ,  1.  ,  3.  ],
       [ 2.  ,  4.  ,  2.  ,  1.75,  4.  ,  2.  ,  1.  ],
       [ 1.5 ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  4.  ,  3.  ],
       [ 2.  ,  3.  ,  2.25,  2.  ,  3.  ,  2.25,  1.  ]])
```

To take care of the boundary conditions, there are other options for padding. Look at [`numpy.pad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) for more info.

**Approach #2:** This would be a modified version of  convolution based approach listed earlier in `Shot #1`. This is same as that earlier approach, except that at the end, we selectively replace
the zero elements with the convolution output. Here's the code -

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

# Inputs
a = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7],[4,8,9]]

# Convert to numpy array
arr = np.asarray(a,float)

# Define kernel for convolution                                         
kernel = np.array([[0,1,0],
                   [1,0,1],
                   [0,1,0]]) 

# Perform 2D convolution with input data and kernel 
conv_out = signal.convolve2d(arr, kernel, boundary='wrap', mode='same')/kernel.sum()

# Initialize output array as a copy of input array
arr_out = arr.copy()

# Setup a mask of zero elements in input array and 
# replace those in output array with the convolution output
mask = arr==0
arr_out[mask] = conv_out[mask]
```

**Remarks:** `Approach #1` would be the preferred way when you have fewer number of zero elements in input array, otherwise go with `Approach #2`.

Comment: is it possible to get avg for only specific point in matrix only. Like element where values is `8`

Comment: @Aamirkhan You mean for a specific list/array of coordinates would be the inputs as `i` and `j` and we would find out the mean values for the neighbourhood around those coordinates?

Comment: No, in my matrix, I have some elements value `0`, and I want to get average  value for those 0 elements only

Comment: @Aamirkhan I am not sure if I am following it correctly. Average value of all those 0 elements would be zero of course. Your code deals with neighborhood. How is the concept of neighborhood coming into the picture then?

Comment: sorry for inconvenience. Actually matrix elements with 0 values are identified as missing value. So I want to fill it by getting the average of it's neighbourhood elements. So I want to get average of neighbors of only those elements whose value is 0

Comment: you could use a mask in a comparable way to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019605/set-values-in-numpy-array-to-nan-by-index/30019701#30019701

Comment: @paddyg Yes of course, that's one way. But, if there are very few  zero elements in the input array, that won't be very efficient. So, instead, I implemented sort of a "manual convolution" approach as Shot #2 in the solution.

Comment: @Divakar After posting my comment I came to the conclusion that your shot#2-#1 was the nicest way. My method would have ended up with a 1D array len(R) containing arr_out as that seemed to be the most useful form (used in conjunction with R and C). Good to not have to install scipy. Well done anyway.

Comment: @paddyg Thanks! Agreed on the nicety of the Approach #1 and Approach #2 on the other hand must be easy to follow. `scipy` is useful at times you know!

Comment: @Divakar though I've voted for your answer I posted some interesting timeit() results below...

Answer (score 3):

This is an appendix to comments under @Divakar's answer (rather than an independent answer).

Out of curiosity I tried different 'pseudo' convolutions against the scipy convolution. The fastest one was the % (modulus) wrapping one, which surprised me: obviously numpy does something clever with its indexing, though obviously not having to pad will save time.

fn3 -> 9.5ms, fn1 -> 21ms, fn2 -> 232ms

```
import timeit

setup = """
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
N = 1000
M = 750
P = 5 # i.e. small number -> bigger proportion of zeros
a = np.random.randint(0, P, M * N).reshape(M, N)
arr = np.asarray(a,float)"""

fn1 = """ 
arr_pad = np.lib.pad(arr, (1,1), 'wrap')
R,C = np.where(arr==0)
N = arr_pad.shape[1]
offset = np.array([-N, -1, 1, N])
idx = np.ravel_multi_index((R+1,C+1),arr_pad.shape)[:,None] + offset
arr[R,C] = arr_pad.ravel()[idx].sum(1)/4"""

fn2 = """
kernel = np.array([[0,1,0],
                   [1,0,1],
                   [0,1,0]]) 
conv_out = signal.convolve2d(arr, kernel, boundary='wrap', mode='same')/kernel.sum()
mask = arr == 0.0
arr[mask] = conv_out[mask]"""

fn3 = """ 
R,C = np.where(arr == 0.0)
arr[R, C] = (arr[(R-1)%M,C] + arr[R,(C-1)%N] + arr[R,(C+1)%N] + arr[(R+1)%M,C]) / 4.0
"""

print(timeit.timeit(fn1, setup, number = 100))
print(timeit.timeit(fn2, setup, number = 100))
print(timeit.timeit(fn3, setup, number = 100))
```

Comment: There is this padding needed to take care of the boundary conditions and then use elements from the padded array. So, those surely add up to the overhead and thus the runtime for a generic case. But, that in-situ substitution is nice work!

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy` and `scipy.ndimage`, you can apply a "footprint" that defines where you look for the neighbours of each element and apply a function to those neighbours:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

# Getting neighbours horizontally and vertically,
#   not diagonally
footprint = np.array([[0,1,0],
                      [1,0,1],
                      [0,1,0]])
a = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]]
# Need to make sure that dtype is float or the
#   mean won't be calculated correctly
a_array = np.array(a, dtype=float)

# Can specify that you want neighbour selection to
#   wrap around at the borders
ndimage.generic_filter(a_array, np.mean, 
                       footprint=footprint, mode='wrap')
Out[36]: 
array([[ 3.25,  3.5 ,  3.75],
       [ 3.75,  4.  ,  4.25],
       [ 4.25,  4.5 ,  4.75]])
```

Comment: is it possible to get avg for only specific point in matrix only. Like element where values is `8`