# Efficient way to loop through numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hi I have array with a number of nan values. I am looking for a way to estimate values for those nan values through plane defined by other finite data. The plane covering the full dimension more than 1000*1000 will be an exaggeration of data. So my idea is to loop through each nan value location with window of 20*20 and find the plane defined by the data avialable in that window and estimate the value at the center of window. But the process takes a quite some time to process. So I was looking if anyone could suggest me an efficient way to do it. I would be thankful.

```
dim = np.shape(data)
row, col = np.where(np.isnan(data))
a = row > 10
b = row < dim[0] - 10
c = col > 10
d = col < dim[1] - 10
row = row[a & b & c & d]
col = col[a & b & c & d]
interdata = np.zeros(np.shape(data))
interdata[np.isfinite(data)] = data[np.isfinite(data)]
for ii,jj in zip(row,col):
        block = data[ii - 10:ii + 10, jj - 10:jj + 10]  # data in 11 by 11 window
        if not np.all(np.isnan(block)):
            block[block > 2 * np.median(
                block[np.isfinite(block)])] = np.nan  # replace the outliers greater than twice the median by nan.
            pointvalue = block[np.isfinite(block)]
            loc = np.ones((pointvalue.shape[0], 3))
            loc[:, 0:2] = np.transpose(np.where(np.isfinite(block)))
            C, _, _, _ = sp.linalg.lstsq(loc, pointvalue) # plane fitting
            interdata[ii, jj] = C[0] * 10 + C[1] * 10 + C[2] # estimation of value from coefficients defining plane
```

It might somehow look like a duplicate question but I looked a lot of similar questions that have been asked before. Most of them were dealing with the continuous data so avoiding loop worked for them.

Comment: also, I can't really figure out why you're code isn't looking at block size 20x20

Comment: It is, actually.Besides, you are creating new nan values "as you go along", when doing the loops. Those ones will not be interpolated, will they? I think you need to check carefully what you are doing with all that complicated code, because I doubt it's doing what you think it's doing. Split the problem in several pieces until you are sure!

Comment: @paddyg: sorry my mistake. Lets say its 20 by 20 window. The size of window is one of the variable that is a subject to chage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting, as far as I see, with a wrong premise: that row and col are independent! You need those rows and columns where [a & b & c & d]. Otherwise you are accepting the rows of some points and then the columns of OTHER points. Then you do a loop over each element of the rows and within it, each elements of the columns. This is doing NxN operations for N nan points! If you assume that your wrong points are (250, 430) and (160, 470) you are "fixing": (250, 430), (250, 470), (160, 470) AND (160, 430). I recommend:

```
whr = numpy.where( (col < ...) & (col > ...) & (row < ...) & (row > ...))
for rr,cc in zip(row[whr],col[whr]):
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out. I have corrected to my knowledge in the update. But still the looping question remains unanswered. +1 for pointing out mistake.

Comment: No, the mistake is still there. You are looping through ALL the columns for each row. Look at my example, which assumes two points with nan as value. You are going through the two points fixing them, and through another two that might have been perfectly valid points! Meaning you are doing O(N^2) where you should be doing O(N) operations.

Comment: That should considerably reduce your computing time. Still worried about you creating more nan values "on the fly".

Comment: Thank you for your concern. But I think I am avoiding nan values for the estimation of the plane and if the window is all nan values then I am skipping the whole window. So those nan values are expected. But as far as I see the result, it looks reasonable. Anyway, what makes you think it would create nan values? May be I am not able to see this angle.

Comment: Ok, sorry I wasn't clear enough. This is what you do:
- create block as a select part of data, a slice. 
- modify block by setting to nan all the values above 2 median values
This modification is being transferred to data, even if you didn't intend to. Try in your command line: 
a = numpy.array( [[9,1,2],[3,2,3],[5,4,3]])  
b = a[0:2,0:2]            
b[0,0] = 0             
print a

Comment: Okay now I get it. I was actually looking for solution to that problem. I remember unlike other scripting language, python uses tag to object. But how can I deal with that. Any idea? It doesn't creates the nan value in my code but indeed affects the interpolation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77848/discussion-between-jblasco-and-abhishek-manandhar).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. I used multiprocessing over the method you suggested and it gives acceptable result.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something similar to the 'pseudo' convolution method here?

[Python get get average of neighbours in matrix with na value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068271/python-get-get-average-of-neighbours-in-matrix-with-na-value/30082326#30082326)

Obviously 11x11 is much more messy than 3x3 (which was a bit messy already) but could you manage with a slightly smaller sample area to average over?

EDIT, have you compared the difference between doing your least squares plane fitting estimate and just averaging the values in the surrounding points?

EDIT2, have you tried any of the scipy interpolations, they may be faster?

EDIT3, following up my own thoughts on this I thought it would be quite easy to test this. To do 1000x1000 takes a fraction of a second to do 20 anneals, with bigger arrays it takes ages to set up but runs very fast if the strides are increased in the interpolate object (i.e to 100)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

data = np.array([[i + 0.1 * j for i in range(1000)] for j in range(1000)])
data = data * (1.0 + np.random.randn(*data.shape) * 0.2)
data[np.random.randint(100,900,100),np.random.randint(0,999,100)] = np.nan

row, col = np.where(np.isnan(data))
data[row, col] = 0.0 ### first patch zeros in to stop nan killing interpolate
yind = np.arange(0, data.shape[0], 10, dtype=np.int)
xind = np.arange(0, data.shape[1], 10, dtype=np.int)
for i in range(20): ### repeat to 'anneal' to steady state could test dz each loop
  interp = interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(yind, xind, data[::10,::10])
  data[row, col] = data[row, col] * 0.5 + interp.ev(row, col) * 0.5
```

EDIT4 - may need smoothing argument in RectBivariateSpline(), can experiment

Comment: Yes! I have averaging as one of the option where I just average the nearest finite values. However, when the data values are clustered to one side or one corner of window the average is not the best way i guess.

Comment: did you fix this? My modified suggestion is very fast but I would be interested to know how it compares with whatever followed from your excursion into 'chat'

Comment: It indeed is fast. But the problem, if I am not thinking stupid, would be (a) I am using zero values at the location of nan values to stop it from killing the interpolation which could produce some bias, chances are the compensation through iterations might not be enough. (b) The whole area is my data is difficult to be defined by a single complex surface. It is the reason I am looking for piecewise simple surface. Result with your code looks obviously better than what I tried before by using all data except nan in scipy griddata. But the plane fitting result looks better. only problem speed

Comment: Hi yes I think it needs a bit of playing around to get an optimum result. And it may not be quite as good at the end. With s=0 (default) it just interpolates which is a bit like the mean of neigbours approximation. However increasing s produces a smoothing effect, trending towards your plane fitting, but probably better as using a 3 term spline. I put a print() into each iteration and the differences were pretty small by 20 or 30 so I don't think the zero start point is insoluble - again play with the 0.5 merging factor..